# How can I center my div embedded object? (Currently left aligned)

Tags: html, css, alignment, tableau-api, embed

New to html and css and I'm trying to embed a Tableau dashboard (using a random dashboard as an example)

[image: Left aligned, not centered]

But it's being left aligned instead of center. Something that may have fed into this problem is that I'm using padding for the content. Here are the relevant sections extracted:

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 ">
                  <nav>
                    <div class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
                      <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-home" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
                      <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
                      <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-contact" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
                    </div>
                  </nav>

                  <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
                    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">

                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-profile-tab">
                    <div class="container-fluid">


                TABLEAU EMBEDDED CODE--->     <div class='tableauPlaceholder' id='viz1591736430373' style='position: relative'><noscript><a href='#'><img alt=' ' src='https:&#47;&#47;public.tableau.com&#47;static&#47;images&#47;Th&#47;TheStampsinmyPassport&#47;TheStampsinmyPassport&#47;1_rss.png' style='border: none' /></a></noscript><object class='tableauViz'  style='display:none;'><param name='host_url' value='https%3A%2F%2Fpublic.tableau.com%2F' /> <param name='embed_code_version' value='3' /> <param name='site_root' value='' /><param name='name' value='TheStampsinmyPassport&#47;TheStampsinmyPassport' /><param name='tabs' value='no' /><param name='toolbar' value='yes' /><param name='static_image' value='https:&#47;&#47;public.tableau.com&#47;static&#47;images&#47;Th&#47;TheStampsinmyPassport&#47;TheStampsinmyPassport&#47;1.png' /> <param name='animate_transition' value='yes' /><param name='display_static_image' value='yes' /><param name='display_spinner' value='yes' /><param name='display_overlay' value='yes' /><param name='display_count' value='yes' /><param name='filter' value='mobile=' /></object></div>                <script type='text/javascript'>                    var divElement = document.getElementById('viz1591736430373');                    var vizElement = divElement.getElementsByTagName('object')[0];                    vizElement.style.width='1650px';vizElement.style.height='927px';                    var scriptElement = document.createElement('script');                    scriptElement.src = 'https://public.tableau.com/javascripts/api/viz_v1.js';                    vizElement.parentNode.insertBefore(scriptElement, vizElement);                </script>
```

CSS:

```
.tab-content{
  background: rgb(254, 254, 254);
    line-height: 25px;
    border-top:5px solid #006950;
    border-bottom:5px solid #006950;
    border-left:none;
    border-right:none;
    padding:30px 25%;

}
```

Here is the raw embedded code Tableau provides:

```
<div class='tableauPlaceholder' id='viz1591742882598' style='position: relative'><noscript><a href='#'><img alt=' ' src='https:&#47;&#47;public.tableau.com&#47;static&#47;images&#47;Th&#47;TheStampsinmyPassport&#47;TheStampsinmyPassport&#47;1_rss.png' style='border: none' /></a></noscript><object class='tableauViz'  style='display:none;'><param name='host_url' value='https%3A%2F%2Fpublic.tableau.com%2F' /> <param name='embed_code_version' value='3' /> <param name='site_root' value='' /><param name='name' value='TheStampsinmyPassport&#47;TheStampsinmyPassport' /><param name='tabs' value='no' /><param name='toolbar' value='yes' /><param name='static_image' value='https:&#47;&#47;public.tableau.com&#47;static&#47;images&#47;Th&#47;TheStampsinmyPassport&#47;TheStampsinmyPassport&#47;1.png' /> <param name='animate_transition' value='yes' /><param name='display_static_image' value='yes' /><param name='display_spinner' value='yes' /><param name='display_overlay' value='yes' /><param name='display_count' value='yes' /><param name='filter' value='mobile=' /></object></div>                <script type='text/javascript'>                    var divElement = document.getElementById('viz1591742882598');                    var vizElement = divElement.getElementsByTagName('object')[0];                    vizElement.style.width='1650px';vizElement.style.height='927px';                    var scriptElement = document.createElement('script');                    scriptElement.src = 'https://public.tableau.com/javascripts/api/viz_v1.js';                    vizElement.parentNode.insertBefore(scriptElement, vizElement);                </script>
```

I tried doing

`tableauPlaceholder{margin: 0;}`

-in CSS to no avail.

I looked at this guide https://tableauing.wordpress.com/2016/10/31/how-to-center-that-viz-css/

And tried

```
div.myTableauViz {
width: 950px;
margin-left: auto ;
margin-right: auto ;
}
```

But it couldn't work because I'm using container fluid and really don't know my width. I suppose I'm lost, I don't know if it's my pre-existing padding that's causing this left alignment off center or if it's something in Tableau's embed code. My tinkering around in both did not change the situation.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I don't use this tool, but I don't see you putting `<div class='myTableauViz'>` around the embedded code `<div class='tableauPlaceholder' ... etc.>`. Therefore the CSS `div.myTableauViz {...}` does not work. Furthermore, point 4. of the explanation says 'Also ensure that your Viz fits this width. In the embed code you can find the width under `VizElement.style.width`' Which in your case is `1650px` (I'm assuming instead of `950px`).

Comment: Sorry, I was trying out so many different methods so I just copy and pasted the base code to StackOverflow. In one attempt, I did wrap it around <div class='myTableauViz'> and played around with the CSS numbers with no effect.

Comment: Found your problem, read **update 2** in my answer....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I commented before:

*I don't use this tool, but I don't see you putting  around the embedded code . Therefore the CSS div.myTableauViz {...} does not work.*

*Furthermore, point 4. of the explanation says 'Also ensure that your Viz fits this width. In the embed code you can find the width under VizElement.style.width' Which in your case is 1650px (I'm assuming instead of 950px).*

For as far I can see, the below snippet (using `1650px` instead of `950px`) nicely horizontally centers the 'Tableau' in the viewport.

The other code is not complete, so it is impossible for now to fully reproduce the problem (should it still persist).

**UPDATE**

You also need to change `25%` to `0` in `.tab-content { padding: 30px 0 }` because it now pushes the entire 'Tableau' 25% of the total browser width to the right. The new `<div class="myTableauViz">` will do the centering through the `margin-left` and `margin-right` settings.

**UPDATE 2**

After OP posted second pastebin code I found the problem:

- `<div class=”myTableauViz”>` pastebin code uses UTF characters as double quote and the browser does not recognize those as being legal double quotes
- `<div class="myTableauViz">` uses proper (plain text) double quotes HTML recognizes

The extra `<div>` plus CSS is still required, but ignore the comment on `.tab-content`

```css
div.myTableauViz {
  width: 1650px;
  margin-left : auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.tab-content {
  background: rgb(254, 254, 254);
  line-height: 25px;
  border-top: 5px solid #006950;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #006950;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  padding: 30px 25%; /* reverted back to 25% */
/* update 2 ingnore: changed 25% to 0, top/bottom padding only */
}
```

```html
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="myTableauViz">
    <div class='tableauPlaceholder' id='viz1591742882598' style='position: relative'><noscript><a href='#'><img alt=' ' src='https:&#47;&#47;public.tableau.com&#47;static&#47;images&#47;Th&#47;TheStampsinmyPassport&#47;TheStampsinmyPassport&#47;1_rss.png' style='border: none' /></a></noscript><object class='tableauViz'  style='display:none;'><param name='host_url' value='https%3A%2F%2Fpublic.tableau.com%2F' /> <param name='embed_code_version' value='3' /> <param name='site_root' value='' /><param name='name' value='TheStampsinmyPassport&#47;TheStampsinmyPassport' /><param name='tabs' value='no' /><param name='toolbar' value='yes' /><param name='static_image' value='https:&#47;&#47;public.tableau.com&#47;static&#47;images&#47;Th&#47;TheStampsinmyPassport&#47;TheStampsinmyPassport&#47;1.png' /> <param name='animate_transition' value='yes' /><param name='display_static_image' value='yes' /><param name='display_spinner' value='yes' /><param name='display_overlay' value='yes' /><param name='display_count' value='yes' /><param name='filter' value='mobile=' /></object></div>                <script type='text/javascript'>                    var divElement = document.getElementById('viz1591742882598');                    var vizElement = divElement.getElementsByTagName('object')[0];                    vizElement.style.width='1650px';vizElement.style.height='927px';                    var scriptElement = document.createElement('script');                    scriptElement.src = 'https://public.tableau.com/javascripts/api/viz_v1.js';                    vizElement.parentNode.insertBefore(scriptElement, vizElement);                </script>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So the website is very text heavy and I would like to keep the padding, but break the embedded object out of padding and have it just centered smack dab in the middle. Here is the pastebin for the full HTML code: https://pastebin.com/KqU4gJNY

Comment: Hey Rene, things are starting to shift! That's good news. So I'm a bit confused, the double quotes I'm using aren't valid? Also, the the embedded object has moved farther to the right instead horizontally centered on the screen. https://i.imgur.com/6DOEOVG.png is the result I'm seeing on my screen right now. So the plan moving forward is to manipulate div.myTableauViz {} in the CSS first and apply the padding to <div class="tab-content"> afterwards? Thanks for sticking around and helping this newbie out.

Comment: For as far as I can tell, only `<div class="myTableauViz">` had the faulty double quotes (just did a scan in the pastebin code). The shifting right may be the `padding: 30px 25%` after all. What you are doing is put 30px space on top/bottom and on left/right 25% of its total size. 25% of 1650px added to either side of the Tableau cause the right shift (as by default HTML reads from left-to-right, in right-to-left reading countries it would shift left. You can check this by putting `dir="rtl"` or `dir="ltr"` in `<body>`). In the mean time, I'm going to check another option...

Comment: Thanks, here's a mockup I made of the desired end result. https://i.imgur.com/6KndQz3.png

Comment: @Anonymous using `transform: translateX(-22%)` instead of `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;` in `div.myTableauViz {...}`will work, this leaves the padding in `.tab-content` intact. You will need to fiddle with the percentage a bit to get it 100% right (and do this for all individual Tableaus you plan to insert). What you are actually doing is moving the Tableau left and go over the 25% left padding of `.tab-content`.

Comment: Your translateX solution works for me! Thank you very much for your help!